# Django 2.0 + Sublime Text 3 + Windows, how can I start

Tags: django, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I'm beginner in the python (sure not so novice, but it's not important)
So, I'm gonna create web-app with using Django 2.0 in Sublime Text 3.
In the internet not so many tutorials, special for Windows. To all other, they are all using PyCharm and hit "auto create project with venv".
Due to it, I can't start! 
I want to know if Sublime Text 3 has a plugin for work with Django more easy, special if that plugin can create auto project with venv.

Sorry for question not about code problem, but that problem so bad for me now!

Comment: Please show some code that you attempted - that will make it easier for others to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have Python and Django installed. Django has a list of commands in which you can run from your CMD and create projects and apps. Ejemplo:

```
$ django-admin startproject mysite
```

Automatically create the folders and files necessary for its execution and excellent operation.

```
mysite/
manage.py
mysite/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
```